# Root privliges on UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to upload files to my MP3 player from my UBUNTU 16.04 but it states the following error:
"You don't have the right permissions to extract archives in the folder "571A-A01E""

So I tried to find the right root privliges, so I typed in the terminal 
"gksudo nautilus" to have root privliges but it seems I cannot write to this MP3 player from my machine.
I checked the properties of this MP3 player:
the owner has permissions to create and delete files on this player but the group doesn't have permissions to read and write, I tried to change it but I all the time get the following error:"
Sorry, could not change the permissions of “571A-A01E”: Error setting permissions: Read-only file system".

I am getting nutsy, can anyone help with this?
Thanks!

Comment: It's a read-only file system, so it's not a permissions issue. Either the drive was mounted READ-ONLY, it's been hardware made READ-ONLY (eg. switching or setting on device stopping write), OR  errors on device have been detected so it was re-mounted RO to prevent errors getting worse. Did you mount it RW or RO?  Have you looked in logs for errors & re-mounting to RO post-mounting etc.

Comment: @quiverc how to check for the errors?

Comment: Can someone help me here?

Comment: When the device is mounted, you can check logs (eg. `dmesg`) to check for messages. If you mount from CLI (command line) the messages appear on screen which is the easiest in my opinion (GUI tends to hide scary messages from users thus the need to look at logs). I'll provide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting but I'm unsure what type of device.  `fsck` (file-system check) will only work if the device itself is not preventing write (ie. forcing RO). You haven't said how you mounted it so currently we don't know if you mounted RO, or because inconsistencies were found